# Find the roots of this 6th degree polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hey guys I'm reviewing for a test and I'm getting stuck on one part, I can't remember what to do next.

$x^6+16x^3+64$

$(x^3)^2+16x^3+64$

let $x^3=w$

$w^2+16w+64$

$(w+8)^2$ now substitute again

$(x^3+8)^2$

Now what do I do?

Comment: From $w^2+16w+64=0$ find the roots of quadratic polynomial $w$ then put $w=x^3$

Comment: So, you take all three cube roots of $-8$, twice.

Comment: Okay so I got -2 which is one of them, how do I find the two imaginary solutions?

Comment: Well, you know what the three cube roots of $1$ look like, no? You can multiply those with the cube root you already have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can actually factor anything in the form $x^3+a^3$ into $(x+a)(x^2-ax+a^2)$.

$x^3+8$ can be factored into the following:
$$x^3+8 = x^3+2^3 =(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)$$
We actually have $(x^3+8)^2$, however we are setting this value to equal $0$ to find the roots so we can just take the square root of both sides and obtain:
$$x^3+8 = 0$$
$$(x+2)(x^2-2x+4) = 0$$
We know now that $x+2 = 0$ so $-2$ is a solution. We also know that $x^2-2x+4=0$ gives us a solution. So if we use the quadratic formula, we get:
\begin{align*}
\frac{-(-2)\pm\sqrt{(-2)^2-4\cdot1\cdot4}}{2\cdot1}&= \frac{2\pm\sqrt{-12}}{2} \\
&= \frac{2\pm2\sqrt{3}i}{2} \\
&= {1\pm\sqrt{3}i}
\end{align*}
So our solutions are:
$$\boxed{-2, {1+\sqrt{3}i}, {1-\sqrt{3}i}}$$

Comment: you said $x^3+a$ (im assuming the a^3 was a mistake) can be factored using that formula, is there one for $x^3-a$? and thank you!

Comment: @TheNewGuy   $a^3$ is actually not a mistake because here $a = 2$ because $2^3 = 8$. Think of it like that. I hope my edit (line 3) kind of clears up any confusion about that. $x^3-a^3 = (x-a)(x^2+ax+a^3)$. I hope this helps! If you still need anymore explanation please do not hesitate to comment

Comment: Oh, I see, like this : http://images.flatworldknowledge.com/redden/redden-eq06_153.jpg      Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @TheNewGuy it is exactly like this. Glad I could help and clear things up for you!

Answer (score 1):

Then you have to solve $x^3+8=0$:
\begin{align*}
x^3+8=0\Longleftrightarrow
x^3=-8
\end{align*} 
But
$$
-8=8(-1)=8e^{i\pi}
$$
Thus
$$
x=2e^{ki\pi/3}\;\;\;\;k=0,1,2.
$$
Hence
$$
x^6+16x^3+64=(x^3+8)^3=(x-2)^3(x-2e^{i\pi/3})^3(x-2e^{2i\pi/3})^3
$$